# Activating Eclipse Django Editor on OS X

Tags: django, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I installed a plugin for Eclipse called [Django Editor](http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/).  I can't figure out how to use it.  The editor is not in my list of editors so I cannot do "Open with Django Editor" on a file nor associate a file extension with it.  It appears nowhere in my preferences.  How can I activate this editor?

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8 and Eclipse 3.5.2 Galileo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you installed it properly, it should show up when you edit .html files as a context item.[alt text http://xs.to/image-0DAF_4BE630E5.jpg](http://xs.to/image-0DAF_4BE630E5.jpg)

Comment: I got it to work after I switched to the 64-bit version running with Java 1.6.  I'm not sure why but it did not work when I used the 32-bit version running with Java 1.5.  One of those factors probably is related.